# Using Spring EL in native Query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

Is it possible to use Spring Expression Language in a native query? I tried but faced exceptions. Also, I searched but couldn't find an obvious answer.
For example:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE id=? and status= :#{T(com.test.constants.PrjConstants).TABLE_PENDING_STATUS_CODE}", nativeQuery = true)
public Integer isThereAnyPendingRecord(String id);
```

Comment: What is the intended meaning of `:#{1+1}` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I mentioned a sample. I edited the question after your request.

Comment: You can't do this.  Just use a `?` or named parameter and then bind the constant `TABLE_PENDING_STATUS_CODE` to it.

Comment: Could you please write your exact point as an answer?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Also please let me know as an answer is it possible to use SPEL in native query or not?

Comment: You are not using the `processId` parameter. Is that intended?

Comment: Also, check this answer. It might be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73279670/passing-parameters-into-query-annotation/73280879#73280879

Comment: @JettoMartínez Regarding your first comment, my bad. I edited the question and solved it. Regarding your second comment, si, you mean it's possible to use SpEl in native query, am I right? but why couldn't use it? I'm using spring boot 2.5.4

Comment: Without the trace, I can only guess, but what I can see that can throw an error is the mixing of porisitional parameters and SpEL. You cannot mix them. You either only use ?, :, ?#{} or :#{} for your parameters. SpEL is meant to be used when you pass to your query a POJO or an entity, to access to their properties, not really for accessing external resources.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you cannot mix expressions. Also, if `TABLE_PENDING_STATUS_CODE` is a constant, you can just concatenate it, as that String must be final. Finally, why use SpEL here? Regular positional parameters would do the trick just fine.

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE id=? and status= " + PrjConstants.TABLE_PENDING_STATUS_CODE, nativeQuery = true)
public Integer isThereAnyPendingRecord(String id);
```

Where `TABLE_PENDING_STATUS_CODE` **must be final**.

SpEL is not the tool for this IMO, but if you want to use it, that would be

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE id=?#{[0]} and status= " + PrjConstants.TABLE_PENDING_STATUS_CODE, nativeQuery = true)
public Integer isThereAnyPendingRecord(String id);
```